# How can I convert a date to another format at run time in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, date

I have a date string coming from user input in the format of `DD/MM/YYYY` and I need to match it against a date column in our database in the format of `DD-MON-YY`.

Example input is `01/01/2015` and example date column in our database:

```
SELECT MAX(creation_date) FROM orders;

MAX(creation_date)
------------------
06-AUG-15
```

I need to query in the format:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE creation_date = 01/01/2015
```

and somehow have that converted to `01-JAN-15`.

Is it possible with some built-in Oracle function?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE creation_date = to_date('01/01/2015','MM/DD/YYYY')`

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_date`, if the column in the table is in date format

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Answer (score 0):

`to_char` allows you to specify different formats in a SQL statement.

Example:  `to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY')` will display 06-AUG-2015 for today's date.

[TO_CHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_date` to compare your date column to a date string, but be careful in doing so since your date column may include a time component that isn't showing when selecting from your table.

If there is no index on your date column, you can truncate it during the comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE TRUNC(creation_date) = TO_DATE('01/01/2015','mm/dd/yyyy');
```

If there is an index on your date column and you still want to use it then use a ranged comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
 WHERE creation_date >= TO_DATE('01/01/2015','mm/dd/yyyy')
   and creation_date  < TO_DATE('01/01/2015','mm/dd/yyyy')+1;
```